# How to use low-level driver APIs with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-data, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongoDB. But I don't want to map my result to a domain class. Also, I want to access low level MongoAB APIs in few cases. But I want spring to manage the connections pooling etc.

How can i get an instance of `com.mongodb.MongoClient` to perform low level operations. 
Here is what I am trying to do :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB local = mongoClient.getDB("local");
DBCollection oplog = local.getCollection("oplog.$main");
DBCursor lastCursor = oplog.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("$natural", -1)).limit(1);
```

Or I simply want a JSON object / DBCursor / DBObject.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way

```
@Autowired MongoDbFactory factory;
DB local = factory.getDB("local");
DBCollection oplog = local.getCollection("oplog.$main");
DBCursor lastCursor = oplog.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("$natural", -1)).limit(1);
```

Where

```
MongoDbFactory is an interface provifed by spring-data-mongo that can obtain a        
com.mongodb.DB object and access allthe functionality of a specific MongoDB database   
instance
```

your configuration file should contain these informations :

```
<bean id="mongoFactoryBean"
class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="port" value="27017"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoDbFactory" 
class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="local"/>
</bean>
```

doing it like that, spring should stay managing your connection pool.

Answer (score 3):

You usually perform low level access through `MongoTemplate`'s `execute(…)` methods that take callbacks giving you access to the native Mongo driver API.

```
 class MyClient {

   private final MongoOperations operations;

   @Autowired
   public MyClient(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
     this.operations = operations;
   }

   void yourMethod() {

     operations.execute(new CollectionCallback<YourDomainClass>() {
       YourDomainClass doInCollection(DBCollection collection) {
         // here goes your low-level code
       }
     });
   }
```

The advantage of this template approach is that the `MongoTemplate` instance backing the `MongoOperations` interface will still take care of all resource management and exception translation (converting all Mongo specific exceptions into Spring's `DataAccessException` hierarchy).

However, for your concrete example you could just go ahead and do the following directly:

```
 Query query = new Query().with(new Sort(DESC, "$natural")).limit(1);
 DBObject result = operations.find(query, DBObject.class, "oplog.$main");
```

Here you can mix and match the type you pass into the `find(…)` method to let the template convert the result into a `Map` or a domain object if needed. As indicated above you also get resource management and exception translation which your sample code above is missing.